# Dress / Skirt weight between thighs major clipping

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, topology, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

I've searched this exchange and several other sources for a good solution, and to be honest most second life creators also have this issue, but I just know there HAS to be a better solution. Basically I'm wondering is there ANY way to fix the clipping that occurs during a walk cycle (or really an bending of the hips), so that it will move more cohesively? I have adjusted the weights of the upper legs and pelvis ad nauseum.

Here's a gyazo clip of the animation and the clipping which is just about as good as I can get it. https://gyazo.com/0cd721118d7c5cd6a38a8032801a3f9f

Here's a pic of the topology.
[image: dress topology]

[image: dress weight paint]

This is for second life, so if anyone here creates content, I would greately appreciate any advice you could give. I'm also curious about somehow adding physics to the dress to allow the movement but unsure if SL can handle the import.

Blender version 3.6.6

Have most add-ons if that's any option.

13K faces (with solidify already applied).

Blend File https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hnB9gEwKfaFqu-04VrwaSX46pnSlpO90?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hello please share the object with its armature so that can give a try (remove the parts that are not useful): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: yayyy great, thanks. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hnB9gEwKfaFqu-04VrwaSX46pnSlpO90?usp=sharing

Comment: it asks for an authorization   ;)

Comment: ugh, hold on sorry i'm  new to this. try now. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hnB9gEwKfaFqu-04VrwaSX46pnSlpO90?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's any magic trick here, you need to weight paint a bit to avoid the overlapping, put the *Weight* and the *Strength* values at one:

[image]

Sometimes move a bit some vertices:

[image]

A bit of painting again:

[image]

Comment: ok great, i'll try that, thanks so much!

Comment: for context, i had already weight painted when I handed it over to u lol....the walk cycle kills it. sigh.

Comment: I think it still needs some weight paint corrections

Comment: i've really got it as good as I can, given the body in second life and the upload constraints. I was hoping to hear of a trick like....idk maybe add a box and parent it to the bottom or something i don't know...